# Yii2 can't find files when running multiple applications with common directory

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm running `Yii2` and I have up until recently been working within a single application; however I needed to start adding an admin area and I didn't start with the advanced application template, just the basic one, but still move some directories around then and everything worked fine.

Now I have a directory structure like this...

```
admin/
    system/
        controllers/
        models/
        views/
    index.php
common/
    vendor/
    .bowerrc
    composer.json
    composer.lock
    yii
    yii.bat
console/
css/
images/
js/
system/
    controllers/
    models/
    views/
index.php
```

So as you can see, the `root` dir acts as the `web` dir and the `system/` dir acts as the `application` dir for the `frontend`.

The *frontend* of the site works absolutely fine, but I am having issues with the `admin` section.

Within the `admin` dir, the `base` dir acts as the `web` directory the `admin/system/` acts as the `application` directory.

This is the error I get when attempting to access: `admin/staff/login`

> Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
>       The file or directory to be published does not exist: common\vendor\bower/jquery/dist

This is the contents of the `admin/index.php` file:

```
// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../common/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../common/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../common/config/constants.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/system/config/main.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Here are the contents of the `admin/system/config/main.php` file:

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/../../../common/config/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'version' => '0.1',
    'vendorPath' => 'common\vendor',
    'defaultRoute' => 'site/index',
    'bootstrap' => [
                    'log',
                    'common\base\Settings',
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'enableCookieValidation' => false,
            'enableCsrfCookie' => false,
            'csrfParam' => '_admin_csrf',
        ],
        'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                // This data is setup dynamically via the bootstrapping process
            ],
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\Staff',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'loginUrl' => 'staff/login',
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'PHPADMINSESSID',
        ],
        'formatter' => [

        ],      
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            // The below viewPath only acts as the base dir and will be changed during the bootstrap process to append the correct locale dir to it
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            // These are relative to the final value of viewPath
            'htmlLayout' => 'layouts/default-html',
            'textLayout' => 'layouts/default-text',
        ],      
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'app\components\AuthManager',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error'],
                    'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/errors.log',
                ],
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['warning'],
                    'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/warnings.log',
                ],
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['info'],
                    'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/info.log',
                    'enabled' => false,
                ],
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['trace'],
                    'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/trace.log',
                    'enabled' => false,
                ],              
            ],
        ],      
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [

            ],
        ],
        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                    'js'=>[]
                ],
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                    'js'=>[]
                ],
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                    'css' => [],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [         
                '*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@common/languages',
                    //'on missingTranslation' => ['common\components\TranslationEventHandler', 'handleMissingTranslation'],
                ],
            ],
        ],          
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/../../../common/config/db.php'),        
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
                                   'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
                                   'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1','::1']
                                   ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
                                   'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
                                   'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1','::1']
                                   ];
}

return $config;
```

I have deleted by `common/vendor` dir and ran `composer install` again but no change.

Do I have some paths wrong somewhere or what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was this line in the *admin* config file:

```
'vendorPath' => 'common\vendor',
```

`common` does not act as an alias there and I needed to change it to:

```
'vendorPath' => '..\common\vendor',
```

..to correctly reference the `common` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think the path could be

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . /..'/../common/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php'); 
....
```

This could create problems for components called inside other or for which you have not set a specific path (eg jquery). I believe that the cause might be this and then to get around this problem you restore the directory vendors in its default configuration or identify the components that must be loaded with the appropriate path.

Comment: I'll give it a try but why would that be? Doesn't `__DIR__` get your current dir, that being `admin/` so you just need the one `/../` ?

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Complained that it couldn't find those files after I made those changes.

Comment: I have update the answer i hope the suggestion is useful for you.